Phaser 3 collision - ball is disappearing in specific collision situations resulting in NaN values for velocity / position properties
I have a simple basketball shooting game built in Phaser 3. It has a ball, a rim with a point on each side where the ball can bounce off of, and a zone underneath the rim that I use to track for scoring if the ball passes through it. The game is 2D.
I come across specific situations where if I launch the ball with just enough velocity so that it basically collides with the rim at the very peak of its launch and hardly bounces since the velocity is so low at that point, in a sense just sitting on the rim for a bit. It will very shortly after disappear completely. Turning debug mode on and checking the velocity, position, and angle, they all show up as NaN.
Here's the relevant code for the collision detection:
            event.pairs.forEach((pair) => {
                const { bodyA, bodyB } = pair;
                const ballBody = this.throwable.body;

                if (
                    (bodyA.label === 'leftGoalBound' ||
                        bodyA.label === 'rightGoalBound') &&
                    bodyB === ballBody
                ) {
                    console.log('hit a rim');
                    const ballBottom =
                        ballBody.position.y + ballBody.circleRadius;
                    console.log('ball bottom');
                    if (
                        ballBody.velocity.y > 0 &&
                        ballBottom <= this.leftGoalBound.position.y - 10
                    ) {
                        debugger;
                        console.log('pair is active');
                        pair.isActive = true;
                    } else {
                        console.log('pair is inactive');
                        pair.isActive = false;
                    }
                }

                if (bodyA.label === 'goalSensor' && bodyB === ballBody) {
                    console.log('hit goal sensor');
                    const ballBottom =
                        ballBody.position.y + ballBody.circleRadius;
                    const ballX = ballBody.position.x;
                    const leftRimX = this.leftGoalBound.position.x;
                    const rightRimX = this.rightGoalBound.position.x;

                    if (
                        ballBody.velocity.y > 0 &&
                        ballBottom <= this.goalSensor.position.y &&
                        ballX > leftRimX &&
                        ballX < rightRimX &&
                        !this.hasScored
                    ) {
                        this.handleHoopScore();
                    }
                }

                const didBallHitGround =
                    bodyA.label === 'ground' && bodyB === ballBody;
                if (didBallHitGround) {
                    this.resetBall(this.throwable);
                }
            });
        });

I've tried setting the rim and ball to have more bounce, but this starts to ruin gameplay as they get too touchy. I haven't really found any good documentation on what can lead to NaN values during a collision - I've been warned of the typical 'divide by 0', but I don't do any such arithmetic here. I'm rather lost as to what is causing this.

Without knowing matterjs so well, I would have to assume, that that this is not the relevant code since  if a value goes to NaN it must be set somewhere. (althought there was a old issue regarding, somehting similar on github) Have you maybe a timeout function, or are you setting the some values in the handleHoopScore, or some other collision check function?

@winner_joiner I don't have a timeout function but if I detect these NaN values I just reset the ball back to the bottom where the user shoots from. handleHoopScore doesn't do any value setting / changing on the ball itself. I only have one other area where I set the velocity explicityly (outside of resetting the ball, where it goes to 0), and that's on a pointer up event, which has long past when this error occurs.

Thanks for your feedback, than it hast probably something to do with the matter physics engine, phaser uses. I will see if I can reproduce this error, or find something out. (I already added the matterjs tag to your question, so that maybe matterjs experts can help)

I suggest providing a runnable [mcve], preferably as a stack snippet.

@JimmyBlundell I can't really reproduce this issue. Are you maybe scaling the ball  on throwing? this might interact in the velocity calculation. how how are you lastly changing to sensors and back (what is the threshold)? Can you may be use my demo from your last question, to create an example that reproduces your issue? Or some other way to show this, bug?

@winner_joiner I do scale the ball on release, but removing scaling altogether still shows the issue. Let me give your demo another shot here.
